approximation on determinant of a matrix
I wonder if there exists a mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that there exists two constants $c_1,c_2>0$ independent of $n$ holding
\begin{align*}
&{\bf (i)}:\qquad c_1\det(A)\leq f(A)\leq c_2\det(A),\quad {\rm~for~any~symmetric~positive~definite~}A;\\
&{\bf (ii)}:~ {\rm Evaluation~of~}f(A) {\rm~requires~ only~ } \mathcal{O}(n^2) {\rm ~flops }.
\end{align*}

Letting $|A| = 1$ gives $c_1 \leqslant c_2$, but letting $|A|=-1$ gives $c_2 \leqslant c_1$, so actually $c_1 = c_2$ is required. :]

Writing $\det A$ instead of $|A|$ would be clearer.

|A| means determinant of $A$, it has been rewritten.

Thanks for Adayah's comment. Now, $A$ appearing in the inequalities is restricted to an SPD matrix and thus the determinant can not be negative.
